# Fill values in rows of a column based on a condition applied to another column in a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple doubt,say I have a data frame called df

Structure:

```
ID   col1   col2  col3   status
1    1      A            Unmapped
2    2            X      Unmapped
3           C     Q      Unmapped
4                 S      Unmapped
5    4      E            Unmapped
```

I want to fill values in column 'status' based on condition. The condition is if for 1st row in col1 is not equal to blank then 1st row in column status must be 'mapped_one'. If col1 is blank then it must check if row under col2 is not blank, then status must be 'mapped_two' so on and so forth

Expected output:

```
ID   col1   col2  col3   status
1    1      A            mapped_one
2    2            X      mapped_one
3           C     Q      mapped_two
4                 S      mapped_three
5    4      E            mapped_one
```

This is what I tired but this didn't work, all rows were assigned the same value

```
 df.loc[df.col1 != "    ", 'status'] = "mapped_one"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is blank? Is it string `''`?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Yes, an empty string, its not NAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
In [137]:
def func(x):
    return 'mapped' + str(x.first_valid_index())[-1]
df['status'] = df.ix[:, 1:].apply(func, axis=1)
df

Out[137]:
   ID  col1 col2 col3   status
0   1     1    A  NaN  mapped1
1   2     2  NaN    X  mapped1
2   3   NaN    C    Q  mapped2
3   4   NaN  NaN    S  mapped3
4   5     4    E  NaN  mapped1
```

A more generic way would be:

```
In [146]:
def func(x):
    return 'mapped' + str(df.columns.get_loc(x.first_valid_index()))
df.ix[:, 1:].apply(func, axis=1)

Out[146]:
0    mapped1
1    mapped1
2    mapped2
3    mapped3
4    mapped1
dtype: object
```

if just want the col name:

```
In [148]:
def func(x):
    return 'mapped_' + str(x.first_valid_index())
df['status'] = df.ix[:, 1:].apply(func, axis=1)
df

Out[148]:
   ID  col1 col2 col3       status
0   1     1    A  NaN  mapped_col1
1   2     2  NaN    X  mapped_col1
2   3   NaN    C    Q  mapped_col2
3   4   NaN  NaN    S  mapped_col3
4   5     4    E  NaN  mapped_col1
```

Comment: Hats off for the speed and accuracy, could you modify your answer to work with column names and not with index, so even if my data frame structure is different I should be able to work?

Comment: if you changed the first code snippet to: `return 'mapped_' + str(x.first_valid_index())` it would do what you want

Comment: I think you missed 'df['status'] =' part in your 2nd and 3rd snippet